# How to use str_replace on strings that contains arabic characters?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, str-replace, arabic

I am doing a multilanguage project in Laravel 4.2. One of the languages is Arabic. All works well except for parameter replacement using the lanuage files (https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/localization). I will show you with an example in pure PHP. The end result is the same and maybe I can write my own function to fix it.

```
$string = [
   'L143' => ':company_name استعراض وتقييم',
   'L155' => 'تقييم :total_points التقييم يستند إلى',
];
echo str_replace(':company_name', 'Testname', $string['L143']);
echo "\n";
echo str_replace(':total_points', '1234', $string['L155']);
```

Result:

```
Testname استعراض وتقييم
تقييم 1234 التقييم يستند إلى
```

Expected result:

The first example is corect. In the second example the word order seems to be reversed.

Above example is also available in this sandbox: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/91fff23e333b3e090ca72d9ce8eb7a2af6d3f999

I have two questions:

1. How can this problem be solved in "pure" PHP?
2. How can this problem be solved in Laravel 4.2?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not reversed! It shows reversed because it's RTL and in this place shows as LTR.

Comment: @MohammadHamedani I have tried with RTL but cannot get it to work with these kind of strings. Non str_replaced string works fine.

Comment: @DovBenyominSohacheski I dont really see how its a duplicate. The other question only has anwsers regarding how to count arabic words after a replace?

Comment: it is totally normal. It just when Arabic and English are in one sentence, the display order gets missy. use <p style="direction: rtl">TEXT HERE</p> to view text. Also, you can print each word in a separate line to confirm order.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered with this problem in PHP7.2. I've researched a bit and thought the problem is string handling mechanism in PHP. If you want to replace LTR String in RTL Strings, PHP thinks that whole string is RTL. Therefore, create LTR String before replace;

```php
echo str_replace(':total_points', chr(0xe2) . chr(0x80) . chr(0x8e) . '1234', $string['L155']);
```

Also, you can read about RTL string on wiki; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark